# Access server running running on Linux from outside local network

Tags: ubuntu, ip, router, nat

I have a website and a springboot application running on my Linux server. I have configured nat forwarding on my router and when I try to access it with the ip my router shows it works while I’m connected to Wi-Fi but as soon as I switch to mobile data site doesn’t work.

I found out my main router is locked by the service provider and I had connected a lan wire from that to my new router which is on a different floor and I can access the settings of my new router but not the one which was provided by my isp(jio).  I wanted to know if there’s a way to bypass the main router and give public access to my server.

Idk if it’s possible to route from my public ip (which is of my locked router) directly to my new router.

My public is something like 10.7.XX.XX and the ip shown on my router connected to this main router is something like 192.168.29.XXX

If nothing is possible I was thinking of getting a opticfiber converter so I can directly connect to my new router and use nat forwarding. But am not sure if a normal converter would work as the main router was provided by JIO and they have some configuration in that.